# Inserting Variables MySQL Using Python Not showing up in data base

Tags: python, mysql

I'm have some problems and its more then likely something really dumb that i missed and i feel kind bad post something on here about this but if you guys could help it would be nice heres my code

```
    import MySQLdb
# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "testuser", "123", "test")
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()
# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
number = 300
number1 = 5001



sql = "INSERT INTO PARTS (PART_NUMBER) VALUES (%d)"

try:
    number = 300
    # Execute the SQL command

    cursor.execute(sql,(number,))

    # Commit your changes in the database
    db.commit()
    print("Updated!")
except db.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    # Rollback in case there is any error
    db.rollback()
    print("was rolled back")

# disconnect
db.close()
```

after i run it no problems but its not show up in my data base when recall the data back nothing   can someone tell me why ? 
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You should always use `%s`, even for numbers.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO PARTS (PART_NUMBER) VALUES (%s)"
```

Check the first example here: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples . It uses `%s` to the `max_price` variable, which is an int.

Quoted from the link:

> In this example, max_price=5 Why, then, use %s in the string? Because MySQLdb will convert it to a SQL literal value, which is the string '5'. When it's finished, the query will actually say, "...WHERE price < 5".

Comment: i have done that and well it still not showing up in my data base ?

Comment: @user3162030 I don't know why, you have to provide more information about your issue. Your code works here, with the change of this answer.